# JSS Rendering DataSource item Workflow States

Tags: jss

In JSS datasource items, we can see "JSS Development Workflow" added.

In that workflow, there are "Development Mode", "Content Mode" and "Published" states.

In which state of the JSS development lifecycle these different stages are assigned/changed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find information on the workflow states in the JSS docs: https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/fundamentals/dev-workflows/code-first#content-workflow-and-developer-overwrite

> The JSS import process is designed to gracefully skip items to which the configured import user does not have write permission. This allows you to utilize Sitecore Security to prevent the import from overwriting content which should no longer be "developer-owned."
>
> To further facilitate this, JSS includes a content workflow which is automatically applied to all generated templates. This workflow defines Development Mode and Content Mode states to designate the current "owership" of a content item.
>
> Development Mode - Import can overwrite field values and route item layout.
> Content Mode - Import user is denied item write access. Import will skip writes on the item. For route items, this means that any rendering changes or updates to datasource items are also skipped.